# how bind commands from listviewitem template

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have some templates in a ResourceDictionary like this one:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultOrderItem" DataType="{x:Type m:OrderItem}">
    <Grid>
        <!-- Row/Column definition and other TextBoxes omitted -->

        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="DecCount" Padding="5,0,5,0"
                Command="{Binding OnDecCount}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">&lt;</Button>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LabelCount, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="20"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Name="IncCount" Padding="5,0,5,0"
                Command="{Binding Path=OnIncCount}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">&gt;</Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" FontSize="20" Padding="5,0,5,0"
                Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OnPrint}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"> Print </Button>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Text="{Binding PosNum}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 IsReadOnly="True" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="30" Background="Transparent"/>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="10" Text="{Binding LabelType}" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="10" Name="Edit" Margin="3" FontSize="20" Padding="5,0,5,0"
                Command="{Binding OnEdit}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"> Edit </Button>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

That template is used by an UserControl like this:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Name="lstItems"
          AlternationCount="2"
          ItemsSource="{Binding OrderItems}"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource alternatingWithBinding}"
          ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource OrderItemTemplateSelector}"/>
```

I read a lot about command binding, but none of them works for me. As you can see, I tried different variants. I tried different command implementations too. I tried member of RelayCommand, functions in code behind of the view, functions in viewmodel and functions in model (OrderItem class), but none of it triggered.

So I hope, some can shine me a light.

**Subsequent note** (based on BionicCodes comment):
*I use Viewmodel first design, which means, I load a ViewModel and the corresponding View is loaded by dependencies written in xaml declarations.*

Comment: Which command binding doesn't work and how is `OrderItem` defined?

Comment: You must understand that the DataContext of the DataTemplate is always the templated data item, which is the OrderItem in your case. Unless OrderItem defines the commands like OnDecCount, your bindings won't resolve. How to fix it depends on where the commands are defined i.e. which DataContext in your visual tree defines the required commands. It's not clear from the context of your posted code. So you have to figure it out on your own.

Comment: @mm8 until now, none of my tries did work

Comment: @BionicCode - thank you for confirming my fear. I don't understand your question about fixing. Is there a way, that I can bind the commands to the viewmodel of that usercontrol? If I have to implement the commands in the model class - where is room to move the commands to a different class? Call redirection in code behind?

Comment: @BionicCode I use Viewmodel first design, which means, I load a new Viewmodel and the View is loaded by dependency from xaml-declarations

Comment: This is very valuable information that should be part of your question. Otherwise it's not possible to answer it. The command is defined in the DataContext of the parent UserControl?

Comment: I have added an answer that shows how to modify your data binding to make it  work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataContext` of the `DataTemplate` is *always* the templated data item, which is the `OrderItem` in your case. Unless `OrderItem` defines the commands like `OnDecCount`, your bindings won't resolve.

You can use the `Binding.RelativeSource` proerty to traverse the element tree to find the proper `DataContext`.

The following example binds the `Button.Command` property to the `OnDecCount` property that is found in the `DataContext` of the parent `UserControl`. The `Button.CommandParameter` is the clicked `OrderItem`:

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultOrderItem" DataType="{x:Type m:OrderItem}">
  <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=DataContext.OnDecCount}" 
          CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I don't know, why this post has received negative votes!

Comment: Thank you very much for your support! I already read about "RelativeSource" before, but I didn't get the picture. Through your explanation I understood it and was able to move the commands to the ViewModel of the Page (UserControl). So finally, with your help, I managed to arrange the code I want it and as it should be. From my person: BIG THUMBS UP!

Comment: Thank you for your very kind words. I'm happy I could help. I wish you all the best and good luck and fun with your project! Very nice.Take care...

Answer (score 1):

I added Commands like that to the model class:

```
public ICommand CmdIncCounter
{
    get
    {
        if (_cmdIncCounter == null)
            _cmdIncCounter = new RelayCommand(IncrementCounter, CanIncrementCounter);

        return _cmdIncCounter;
    }
}
```

That works, but there are 2 points I would like to change:

- first: I don't like controller code in my model. So if there's a way to move commands out of model class, I would appreciate any hint
- second: the buttons don't change to disabled state, when canExecute returns false. It works, as command is not executed when canExecute returns false, but there's no visual user feedback

Comment: Rather update the question if you're not satified with the answers so far